# Why isn't TcpListener listening?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

We have a C++ v100 application that is processing every event in our system, listening on port 1705, running off the Hostname. (it works perfectly for the C++ app, and we don't want to change anything in the c++ code)  We are trying to intercept some of those events into a C# 4.5.2 solution, simply to display specific events in our new web system.

I have coded the following, in an attempt to listen to port 1705 traffic... but I never receive any data. (I can create events that get sent to 1705)

The following code runs, and it makes it to 'Waiting for a connection', but never makes it to 'Connected!'.  If you see any reason in the following code as to why I wouldn't be receiving data, please let me know:

```
    private void PortListener()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
            var port = 1705;
            var localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName)[0].ToString());

            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            var bytes = new byte[256];

            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                var stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    var data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    //TODO:  Process the data
                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server?.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that youare running two apps that are listening on the same port ?

Comment: I'm going to guess that `localAddr` is not the correct address to bind to.  Change your IP address to `IPAddress.Any` and try again.

Comment: If I change to IpAddress.Any, it throws the exception:  "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'

Comment: @JonathanHansen That's because you can only have one process binding to a port at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are binding/listening to the right ip-address. If you bind/listen on localhost (127.0.0.1) you can only connect from the same host.

Check what

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName)[0].ToString());
```

really produces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this all wrong.  In order to listen to an already opened Port, I need to use a TcpClient to connect and listen.  Only a single TcpListener is allowed per port.  Several TcpClients can connect at once. Sigh.